# Is Entity Translation module compatible with Internationalization and can they be used to translate menus?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I installed the [`entity translation`](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module for Drupal 7 and it works fine.

However, I also want to translate menus and I found that [`Internationalization`](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module can do that.

The question is: are they compatible at all? If I install `internationalization` module will it not break the `entity translation` one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are compatible.

Entity Translation deals with entity translations, and menus in Drupal 7 are not entities, there's no clash between Entity Translation and Internationalization modules.